# Removing wp admin menu item on top bar of admin backend

Tags: menus, admin

I have managed successfully to remove the not needed menu items for user role 'editor'.
Now I have one item left on the top bar that makes Editor add new post page and other items which I need to hide.
Please check the screen shot as I indicate what item is this.
There is a link of this page displayed and I tried but it does not want to go away.

[image: How to remove top menu item - admin backend wp]

I have used the code:

```
/** remove editor dashboard menu */ define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);

function remove_menus(){

remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' ); //Media
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' ); //Pages
remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' ); //Appearance
remove_menu_page( 'post.php' ); //Remove +New
remove_menu_page( 'post-new.php' ); //Remove +New 
remove_submenu_page( 'post-new.php' ); //Edit Page
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=client' ); //Clients
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=offer' ); //Offers
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=portfolio' ); //Portfolio
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=slide' ); //Slides
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=testimonial' ); //Testimonials
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=layout' ); //Layouts
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=template' ); //Templates
remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' ); //Contacts
remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); //Tools
remove_menu_page( 'vc-welcome' ); //Visual Composer
remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' ); //Settings remove_menu_page( 
'wpcf7' ); //contact form

} if(current_user_can( 'editor' )){ add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' ); }
```

So I tried to use:

```
remove_menu_page( 'post-new.php' ); //Remove +New 
remove_submenu_page( 'post-new.php' ); //Edit Page
```

but it does not work.
How could I remove this menu item with all its submenus?

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
function my_admin_bar_render() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-content');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'my_admin_bar_render' );
```

Comment: It works :)  thanks

Comment: I have just realized that your solution removes that top menu item for all users.Is there a way to remove that only for 'Editor' or 'Shop manager" ?

Comment: See updated example. Add additional checks as you need. Or even better - inverse logic, remove menu item if user doesn't have administrator role.